# Updating links using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code so that I can update 3 links at one go. I already have a code that pulls together all the currently used links, then in a cell I update those links to correspond to the updated files within a different folder. Now I am trying to use:

`ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:="File Name", Type:=xlExcelLinks`

to update to the appropriate updated file but in the file name I am trying to pull in the path from a particular cell. for example I have my new path/file in cell C3 of Sheet1, how can I pulll in that particular cell information into the Name:="File Name" portion of the code above.

Thanks for the help

Edit: What I am ultimately trying to do is be able to update a link/file with a click of one button instead of going to Data -> Edit Links and changing the links manually. Every month, the files that need to be updated get added to a new folder created for that particular month so I need it to be able to pull from that folder.

Comment: `Name:=Sheet1.Range("C3").Value`?

Comment: Doesn't work. I also tried ```link = Range("C3"). value``` and then ```ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=link``` ---- I get a run-time 1004 error

Comment: Please specify 1) a sample value in `Sheet1.Range("C3")`, and 2) the specific error message you get.

Comment: sample value: \\majorfolder\folder\subfolder\may2021\xlfile

Comment: I don't think `UpdateLInk` does what you think it does ... it refreshes an existing link. I think you want [`ChangeLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.changelink).

Comment: I am trying to replace the existing link with another one because every month the links get added to a new folder that is created for that month. so in june it would change to june2021

Comment: Yeah definitely sounds like you want `ChangeLink` then.

Comment: Are you saying that when the user clicks on cell C3 (or some other cell), you want that to open the filepath specified in cell C3?